# How to add costs to routes in Anylogic?

Tags: routes, simulation, anylogic, cost-based-optimizer, travel-time

I am creating a model in Anylogic to simulate the container transportation between a port and the hinterland (in a GIS map). I have data on how many trucks are driving between each customer zone and the terminals. I want to add a possible hub in the network, so that trucks can choose to transport containers at night between the terminals and hub (and at day bring them to the customers).

However, I am struggling to find how to add a route (and time of day) choice to Anylogic (based on route costs (based on a travel time matrix I have), hub costs and average waiting times at terminals during specific times of the day). Does somebody know how to add costs to routes in Anylogic?

Comment: There is nothing like this pre-made for you. You have to code things like that yourself, I am afraid. But worth learning that as you can then do anything with AnyLogic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add costs to route the best option would be to create your own custom Java class and have the standard AnyLogic GISroute as a field as well as the cost (and any other variable that you want)

[image]

You can then create routes and assign costs to them and then use this custom field inside your analysis and modelling

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Jaco-Ben Vosloo! I created this Java class and function to assign costs. However, I have a lot of routes that need costs (around 400), so I want to read it from a database. I tried to give an Origin and Destination to my Order agent, but as the Destination can be one of several single agents, I am having a hard time to create a parameter with Destination in the Order... I know this is a bit of a different problem, but do you maybe know how I should start with this?

Comment: I think you can start a new question with "How to read and create routes from a database" ;-) and show us what you have done so far. Here is some help on reading from the database, and then for each entry you create a new version of your custom class. https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/select-cases.html#use-cases-of-reading-data-from-anylogic-database

Comment: I edited my question as I implemented your answer, but only still have to link the function to the choice of actors. Do you know how I can say that the agent should look at a specific route and its costs?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but I am not sure I understand the new question you added. Do you mind asking a new question? Maybe check here for some pointers - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask